# how to change barbuttonitem from edit to done

Tags: iphone

i am placing a toolbar at the top of my view with edit button.

For edit button i am giving action like edit the table as shown below.

```
- (IBAction)editModeForTable {
    [tableview setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"edit button clicked ");
}
```

Now what i need is when i click on edit button i need to change this edit button to done button.

[image: myscreen]

this is myscreen.

when ever i click on edit i need to set edit mode for table and change edit button to done.

similarly when ever i click on done button i need to change that done to edit button and edit mode should be false.

**Update:**

```
- (IBAction)editModeForTable {
    if (buttonClickid == 1) {
        [allLIsts setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        mybutton.style = UIBarButtonSystemItemDone;
        mybutton.title = @"Done";
        buttonClickid = 2;
        NSLog(@"mmm");
    }
    if (buttonClickid == 2) {
        [allLIsts setEditing:NO animated:YES];
        mybutton.style = UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit;
        mybutton.title = @"Edit";
        buttonClickid = 1;
        NSLog(@"ppp");
    }


    NSLog(@"edit button clicked ");

}
```

this is button action where buttonclickid is int.

it executes both conditions why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[btn setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone];
[btn setTitle:@"Done"];
```

Similiar to revert back.
btn is an IBOutlet connected to the button in Interface Builder, or your created UIBarButtonItem.

Your if logic is broken.

```
- (IBAction)editModeForTable {
    if (![allLIsts isEditing]) {
        [allLIsts setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        mybutton.style = UIBarButtonSystemItemDone;
        mybutton.title = @"Done";
        NSLog(@"mmm");
    }
    else  {
        [allLIsts setEditing:NO animated:YES];
        mybutton.style = UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit;
        mybutton.title = @"Edit";
        NSLog(@"ppp");
    }


    NSLog(@"edit button clicked ");

}
```